# How to use Vue's defineAsyncComponent on server where all Vue files have been bundled by Vite

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, vite, npm-package

I have a small Vue + Vite component library that I am using to render custom tables in a project. This library has a Table component that takes a config and data as props. One feature of the library is that you can add an entry in the config that will render a custom, dynamic component in the relevant table cell. This config property looks like this:

```
dynamicComponent?: ((input: string, secondaryInput?: {}) => {
    componentPath: string,
    props: {[index: string]: unknown}
})
```

Then, as the library puts together the content of each cell, it checks for this property, evaluates it, and renders that component from the returned `componentPath`. It renders it like so:

```
const AsyncComp = defineAsyncComponent(() => {
    try {
        return import(/* @vite-ignore */componentPath.value);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
});
```

Working locally in my Vite dev server, I was using something along the lines of this:

```
componentPath: `${import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL}components/AppStatusPill.vue`
```

But now that I have built everything into a single JavaScript file inside a dist/ directory and placed it on a server, this path obviously isn't working anymore, and these async components aren't showing up. I'm getting the following error:

TypeError: error loading dynamically imported module: https://example.com/components/AppStatusPill.vue

...No matter how I adjust the path. I understand that the whole point of an asynchronous component is that it is only loaded at runtime, at the moment it's needed/able to be rendered. But is there a way to have Vite do something with this path at build time to make sure the server can find the chunk when it's needed?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This has been solved. The problem was that the import of the component was happening (rather trying to happen) in the library's code, at which point the project code was already bundled. I have moved the import to the project code which generates a chunk for the relevant component at build time, and now the library is able to locate that.